# Add Page Tab Dialog is autoredirecting but not showing the dialog to add pages

Tags: dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am calling the [Facebook Add Page Tab Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) using the Javascript SDK as follows:

```
var obj = {
    method: 'pagetab'
};
FB.ui(obj, function(response) {
    console.log(response);  
});
```

The dialog shows up on the page and then auto redirects to the same page which is presently open. It doesn't show the options to select the pages as described in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now. The 'display' parameter should be specified explicitly to 'popup'

```
var obj = {
    method: 'pagetab',
    display: 'popup'
};
FB.ui(obj, function(response) {
    console.log(response);  
});
```